# Plot 2d matrix with legend from another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, legend

So say I have the 2d following matrix:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5;
     1,2,3,4,5;
     1,2,3,4,5;
     1,2,3,4,5]
```

and another matrix with the following values:

```
b = [0.3,0.4,0.6,0.9,1.2]
```

Not, I need to plot all the column vectors in a. I can very easily do this with :

```
plot(a)
```

However, I want a legend on the side which also shows just which line in the plot corresponds to what value from b.

I've done this using:

```
legend(b)
```

after the plot line. However, I wasn't sure if this is plotting the correct correspondence as in the first line color in the legend from b is pointing to the first line in a. Could someone tell me if I am right or at least rectify what I'm doing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a handle from `plot` and pass it to `legend`. Also, you need to convert `b` to strings to use it in `legend`.

```
h = plot(a); % returns a vector of handles to the individual plots
legend(h,num2str(b(:)))
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the string matrix syntax of `legend`.  I usually use comma-separated strings or a cell, but this is easiest for this question.